# S3TransferManager after svn update undeclare identifier

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, amazon-web-services

i have strange error. I write a code at home with S3TransferManager (from S3 classes), and commit it. When i did update at work got this strange error. I did try everything, event update AWS frameworks, same problem

*.h file

```
// Amazon AWS imports
#import <AWSRuntime/AWSRuntime.h>
#import <AWSS3/AWSS3.h>
#import <AWSDynamoDB/AWSDynamoDB.h>
#import <AWSSQS/AWSSQS.h>
#import <AWSSNS/AWSSNS.h>
#import <AWSS3/AmazonS3Client.h>
// background thread

@interface UploadVideoController :    UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate, AmazonServiceRequestDelegate>
```

And after update at woek i will get this:

[image]

How can i fix that? thanks

Comment: Import S3TransferManager.h

Comment: As I mention, at home i have working copy, but clone at work computer give me this error. So i this is something deeper then just import. Anyway thanks for do fast answer

Answer (score 1):

I am one of the maintainers of the AWS SDK for iOS.  I'm sorry you're encountering problems.

First, you shouldn't need to import both AWSS3.h and AmazonS3Client.h, as the first imports the second.

Secondly, it sounds like you might have a bad header or framework search path in your project.  You might want to remove the frameworks, clear your search paths and then re-add the frameworks to your project.